# Why does HDInsight cluster does not come with pre-installed Scala?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

on HDInsight's masternode, $scala -verion returns an error. It is easily installed via 
$apt-get install scala
but shouldn't scala be installed there by default?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for suggestion. What's the scenario where you need scala to be directly installed on the node? For example, in spark there are couple of other common scenarios that already work:

1. Running Spark commands in command line. This is accomplished through spark-shell which has built-in scala interpreter.
2. Building spark project. This is ussually done through maven or sbt project definition file. Those tools would automatically download correct scala version and compiler based on the project dependencies.

As you said it's not hard to preinstall scala, but we would like to understand the need to do that. In the discussions with customers this didn't come up before.